# convert a generic list to ISet

Tags: c#

Has anyone had to assign a list to an `ISet`? How do I go about and do this?

Say I have the class

```
class Foo
{
  ISet<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to do the following:

```
var foo = new Foo() { Items = new List<Item>() { new Item() } }
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
List<Item> myList = ...
foo.Items = new HashSet<Item>( myList );
```

Keep in mind that a `Set`, unlike a `List`, must contain every element exactly once. Therefore, if `myList` contains multiple copies of some elements, all those copies, except one, will not make it into the set.

Equality of elements (for detecting multiple copies) is defined by the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods. If you would like to use a different definition of equality, you can use the overload of `HashSet` constructor that takes an `IEqualityComparer<Item>`.

Answer (score 9):

`List<T>` doesn't implement the `ISet<T>` interface… So, this isn't possible.

The only classes that implement `ISet<T>` are `HashSet<T>` and `SortedSet<T>`.

The closest you could get would be (if you cut out the unnecessary `List` object in between):

```
var foo = new Foo { Items = new HashSet<Item> { new Item() } };
```